Linking model for rigging
I am trying to seperate the file with model so that I can update it and not create a mess later. However when I link the model, do the library override so that I can manipulate with it and then try to rig I get this error:
"Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Cannot edit library linked or non-editable override object"
I am using AutoRig-Pro for the rigging process.
I've tried to look for the answers but I couldnt find a single mention of someone linking model and then rigging it... they always only link the rig and nothing before. So my question is if anyone here has some expirience and could offer some advise or if such thing is even possible in Blender ?
